# Rewrite Custom Post Type URL slug

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite, url-rewriting, urls, template-hierarchy

Hello StackExchange WP_development :)

I am in a bit of a pickle with this one and i certainly hope you can consult me further. Im helping out with a WordPress site that is build as a "singlesite". The thing that is tricking me is the URL rewrite.

I have looked around on the web for a solution but with no luck.

The site structure is as following

```
-Main page - Page template
 --City 1 - Page template
   ---VIP - Page template
      ----VIP subpage - Page template
 --City 2 - page template
   ---VIP - Page template
      ----VIP subpage - Page template
 --City 3 - page template
   --- EVENTS - Page template
      ----CPT which redirects out of stucture(single event)
```

Here is a example of the URL structure:

```
Current URL(page templates): www.example.com/city/region/vip
Current URL(for the CPT): www.example.com/event/region/beer-pong/
Desired URL(for the CPT): www.example.com/city/region/event/beer-pong
```

And my registered post type is using the following:

```
'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'byer/event' ),
'hierarchical'       => true,
'has_archive'        => false,
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),
```

Normally in quiete fancy with developing in WordPress, but I can simply not wrap my mind arround this....

Unfortunately the URL format is essential, as there is logic developed for the "layers" of the site/pages.

I hope the given information is enough to enlighten you.

WHAT I WANT: to rewrite this URL : /event/region/beer-pong/ to contain 
a City :  city/region/event/beer-pong

WHAT I HAVE: Currently my events made as a Custom Post Type rather than a Page, this can sadly not be changed because the Client won't allow it.

I need your help to solve this!

Answer (score 1):

If the city and region is always `city` and `region` strings, you can do something like this.

For your specific case, you could do it like this:

```
'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'city/region/event' ),
'hierarchical'       => true,
'has_archive'        => false,
'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),
```

If the city becomes some city and the region becomes some region in the URL i.e. city becomes `London` and region becomes `South East`, you have to use `global $wp_rewrite` and write the regular expression to change add the slugs.

You can find more documentation on WordPress Codex - https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite.

Comment: Thanks alot for the reply! I have tried that but without any luck - not sure if i mess up the code. 

City is ALWAYS static
Region is dynamic based of a page ID